# JavaFX: Null Pointer Exception when Setting TextArea Content in Second Window from First Window

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, textarea, fxml

I am using JavaFX and creating two window application one to browse a file and the other to show its content

the Problem is that I am getting null pointer exception when I acssess inputText.setText(filecontent)
As it says inputText is null

```
public class AppController  {


    private Button BrowseButton;


    @FXML
    private void handleBrowseButtonAction(MouseEvent event) {
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        fileChooser.setTitle("Choose a File");
        File selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(BrowseButton.getScene().getWindow());

        if (selectedFile != null) {
            try {
                String fileContent = Files.readString(selectedFile.toPath());
                openFullScreenStage(fileContent);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    private void openFullScreenStage(String fileContent) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("editor.fxml"));
            Parent root = loader.load();

            // Accessing the controller of the editor.fxml
            editorController editorController1 = loader.getController();

            // Assuming TextArea in editor.fxml has the fx:id "inputText"
            /*TextArea textArea = editorController1.inputText;*/

            //editorController1.initialize();
           // editorController1.fakeinitialize();

            editorController1.setInputText(fileContent);



                Stage fullScreenStage = new Stage();
                fullScreenStage.setFullScreen(true);
                fullScreenStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
                fullScreenStage.show();

                //System.err.println("TextArea in editor.fxml is null");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

The controller for  the text area

```
package com.editor.xml_editor;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class editorController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    protected TextArea inputText;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        this.inputText.setText("Hello World");
    }

    public void setInputText(String input) {
        inputText.setText(input);
    }

    // Assuming you want to expose this TextArea


    // This TextArea is used internally



}
```

Fxml for the text Area

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/20" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.editor.xml_editor.editorController">
   <children>
     
      <BorderPane layoutY="26.0" prefHeight="370.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="25.600000000000023">
         
         <center>
            <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.48328877005347587" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
              <items>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                     <children>
                        <TextArea id="inputText" layoutX="15.2" layoutY="48.0" prefHeight="322.0" prefWidth="290.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="16.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                     <children>
                        <TextArea id="outputText" editable="false" layoutX="41.0" layoutY="53.0" prefHeight="322.0" prefWidth="290.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="16.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
              </items>
            </SplitPane>
         </center>
      </BorderPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

I tried all the programming I could

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55668795/javafx-2-independent-windows-at-once/55671730#55671730

Comment: Your xml document details id="outputText" ALSO i cannot see it declared anywhere in code.

Answer (score 3):

The identity attribute is wrong in your FXML document.

You should be using `fx:id`, not `id`.

This:

```
<TextArea id="inputText" . . .
```

Should be:

```
<TextArea fx:id="inputText" . . .
```

Similarly for your other ids defined in FXML like for `outputText`.

By setting `id`, you are only setting the CSS ID, not an FXML reference that can be injected by the loader into a controller which uses the `@FXML` annotation.

The [FXML documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#variable_resolution) isn't really good at documenting this topic, but it says:

> Assigning an `fx:id` value to an element creates a variable in the document's namespace that can later be referred to by variable dereference attributes, such as the "toggleGroup" attribute shown above, or in script code, discussed in a later section. Additionally, if the object's type defines an "id" property, this value will also be passed to the objects `setId()` method.

So `fx:id` also sets `id` (which is used as a CSS identifier), in addition to putting a reference to the object in the namespace which can be extracted and set by the loader on public references in your controller class or references annotated with the `@FXML` annotation.

See the [documentation on controllers and `@FXML`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controllers) for more info and examples.

Comment: I can't believe how easy that was. Thanks, I feel so stupid.